# conversational knowledge of something

Tags: meaning

Example:

> The discussions in this book assume the reader has more than **a conversational knowledge of ANSI C programming**. This book is not a tutorial on the entire language. It is aimed at the advanced beginner to intermediate-level programmer who feels relatively comfortable writing C programs but who has a distance to travel when it comes to the topic of pointers.

What exactly do you think that means? I particularly don't understand how the word *conversational* is used here. *Conversational* usually refers to something that has to do with verbal conversation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Conversational knowledge* of a subject literally means that you know enough about something *to talk with others about it*. Not in academic detail, but a "light" or "social" conversation.

As a prerequisite of a book, it means a basic knowledge - so that you can follow the author's "speech" and further explanations.

Answer (score 1):

I would say *conversation* indicates a general knowledge among the population in general. For example, if you were with a group of friends, you would not talk with them (have a conversation) about detailed C programming, because some of them will have no idea what you are talking about.

So, *general conversation*. You could use the definition of [***conversation***](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/american/conversation):

> 1) the act or an instance of talking together (; specif.,)  *1a)* **familiar talk**; verbal exchange of ideas, opinions, etc.

or

> 5) (obsolete) familiarity based on study or use

Answer (score 0):

It means that you should know at least the basics of the C language before starting the book.

Comment: Well, duh! You know, that is kind of obvious.

Comment: Well, that's exactly the meaning in that context, "basic", apologies if I said a truism to you.